# c++: How to insert Line Feed into sprintf concatenation?

Tags: c++, printf

I am trying to send two commands at once with sprintf. Commands should be separated with 0x0A (LF). I thought I could enter special characters using two slashes, so I am writing:

```
sprintf(tmpstr,"VSET1:%ld.%3.3d\\x0AVSET2:%ld.%3.3d",mv/1000, AbsVal((int)mv%1000), mv / 1000, AbsVal((int)mv % 1000));
```

and it seems only the second command (VSET2) is recognized.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use one backslash, not two. `\x0A` instead of `\\x0A`.

Comment: You only need one slash.

Comment: Use \n in the format string.

Comment: @SidS:  The problem with `\n` is that it is a *line-ending*, not a *linefeed*.  On some platforms `\n` is translated into carriage return *and* linefeed.  Some platforms, it is only carriage return; while on others it is only a linefeed.  A linefeed, by definition, moves the cursor to the next line, same column (as defined by Teletypes).  A *newline* or *line-end* marks the end of a line.

Comment: @Thomas, That is only true if you open a file in text mode.  If you open the file in binary mode, \n is LF and \r is CR.

Comment: Also, if `\n` is translated so is `\x0A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\n` in the format string.  Also, use a single backslash not `\\`.

If you are writing your buffer to a file, open the file in binary mode.

Whether you use `\n` or `\x0A`, you have to open the file in binary mode to avoid non-portable translations.

See [Escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

Answer (score 0):

When you use `\\x0A` in a string literal, the first backslash escapes the second backslash. As a result, the string contains a backslash character, `'\\'`, followed by characters `'x'`, `'0'`, and `'A'`.

To use the character represented by `0x0A`, you need to use `\x0A`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a single backslash instead of two backslashes. Try the statement given below:

```
sprintf(tmpstr,"VSET1:%ld.%3.3d\x0AVSET2:%ld.%3.3d",mv/1000, AbsVal((int)mv%1000), mv / 1000, AbsVal((int)mv % 1000));
```

However, what you have done in your program will print a string `"\x0A"`, rather than an ASCII character (`0xAA` (Line Feed)).

In C, all escape sequences consist of two or more characters, the first of which is the backslash, \ (called the "Escape character"); the remaining characters determine the interpretation of the escape sequence.

C deal with backslashes as escape sequences by default. However, in your program, you have told C compiler to not use your backslash as an escape sequence by adding an extra backslash to your string.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfect. You not only get to insert \n but looks correct in the code. No need for a \ at the end of lines either. I use this for big paragraphs. Personal data has been obfuscated.

```
enter code here
```

wchar_t msg[200];
swprintf(msg, L"XYZ%d: ABCD Limit set to %d%%. %d times it has abcd and xyz rstu %d%%\n" 
                    "Do you want to fix it?\n"
                    "An Yes will fix it\n"
                    "No will ignore it and continue\n" 
                    "Cancel will abort the run\n", xxx, yyy, zzz, aaa);